# Chrome Bookmarks API - using 'Move' to reorder bookmarks in the same folder

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, bookmarks

From the [documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/bookmarks.html#method-move)

```
chrome.bookmarks.move(string id, object destination, function callback)
Moves the specified BookmarkTreeNode to the provided location

id ( string )
destination ( object )
    index ( optional integer )
    parentId ( optional string )
callback ( optional function )
chrome.bookmarks.move(string id, object destination, function callback)
Parameters
```

**The API works as intended when,**

If I move a bookmark to a different folder, to any location(index) - 
If I move a bookmark within the folder and move the bookmark up - that is to a position where the new index is less than the current index -

**The API does not work - when -**

If I move a bookmark within the folder(i.e. parentId is same) and move the bookmark up - that is to a position where the new index is greater than the current index

The resultant position of the book mark is one position above instead of where I wanted it to be..

**For example -**

There is no problem with the api  If I move the bookmark above (new Index < current Index )
i.e - If I have a bookmark at index 3 and want to move it above, that is to index 1, this works fine.

But if I move the bookmark below (new Index > current Index )
i.e - If I have a bookmark at index 1, and want to move it below, that is to index 3
The bookmarks is being placed at 2 i.e  (3-1) = (new Index - 1)

Can we use the 'move' api to reorder book marks within the same folder?
I assumed so since we can use it since 'parentId' in the 'destination' object is optional.

Thanks.

Comment: You've explained that in a very complicated manner! But yes, I have the same issue, 7 years later.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
if(oldIndex < newIndex) newIndex++;
chrome.bookmarks.move(id, {index: newIndex});
```

Comment: Hi from 2019. 
I can confirm that OP's issue is still here, and that this workaround seems to be working well.  
It honestly seems a bug on the Bookmark API to me.

Comment: Hi from 2021, it still doesn't work correctly =)

Comment: Hi from June 2023, this issue still persists. There goes an entire day of debugging my code.